# Организовать обновление CMS

Tags: php, архитектура

Добрый день. 
Появилась следующая задача: написать CMS для ~18 сайтов, и встал вопрос об обновлении версий CMS и добавлении новых модулей.

Дело в том, что помимо правок, которые будут вносить владельцы сайтов, иногда придётся выпускать обновления: к примеру, создавать новые модули или обновлять нынешние. И дело в том, что делать это руками очень неудобно, особенно если нужно часто менять код и несколько простых строчек. Поэтому, стоит вопрос об автоматическом обновлении CMS. Как это сделать, чтобы не было конфликтов с правками пользователя? Как вовсе реализовать всю систему обновлений? Буду рад ссылками на статьи и пр.

P.S. На данный момент, используется старая система, в которой много изъянов, поэтому её и нужно переписывать с 0. Там некоторые модули, на которых чаще всего изменения, при роутинге тянутся с определенного сервера. Но из-за этого часто бывают конфликты в дизайне, тексте и т.д.

Comment: Владельцы будут вносить правки в код CMS? Или они буду только вносить правки в содержимое?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, хм. По-сути, может изменяться чуть контроллер и модель(CMS будет с использованием паттерна MVC), но больше всего будет вью затронут, думаю. Возможно, стоит реализовать какую-либо проверку и если содержимое модуля не отвечает какому-либо стандарту не устанавливать обновление, а сообщать об этом пользователю?

Comment: делаете ядро CMS которое трогать юзерам не рекомендуется, если им нужны какие-то свои дополнительные фишки, то тут решат самописные модули (без ваших обновлений), они копируют какой-либо компонент и сами допиливают, либо наследуются и переопределяют. И соответственно не меняешь существующее API и тогда у юзеров не будет конфликтов. Это что касается архитектуры CMS. А вот по обновлению лучше всего будет если закинете это всё в репозиторий, например Composer, если конечно готовы кодом поделиться :) Ну или пишете модуль обновлений для CMS, чтобы скачивала нужные папки с вашего сервера обновлений.

Comment: кто будет вносить изменения в код - вы или пользователи?

Comment: Мне одному кажеться странным, что в первую очередь не смотряться готовые решения? Тот же wordpress посволяет делать multisite https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/ultimate-guide-multisite. Да и поддержка и поиск разработчиков сильно упростяйться. Если wordpress не нравиться всегда есть огромное количество других решений drupal, liferay ce... Уверен что и под ноду что то будет.